# Stimulsoft reports Allowing editable field to be edited after exporting to pdf using jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, stimulsoft

I am unable to edit the fields (which I set editable true in Stimulsoft report) after exporting to PDF.
I am generating a Stimulsoft report through JSP.

I am using a trial version of Stimulsoft.

I tried below code in JSP but still not working,

StiPdfExportSettings pdfExportSettings = new StiPdfExportSettings();
pdfExportSettings.setAllowEditable(StiPdfAllowEditable.Yes);
StiExportManager.exportPdf(report, pdfExportSettings, response.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 0):

I got the answere of this question , i asked the same question to stimulsoft customer care executive he said it is not possible through java. currently this feature is not preset in stimulsoft.They will add this feature to new release of stimulsoft software.